# Jetpack Compose: how to disable gesture detection on children

Tags: gesture, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a built-in `Modifier` that disables any gesture detection / pointer input interaction of its children?

e.g.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Foo() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.gesturesEnabled(enabled = false)) {
        BasicText(text = "Hello", modifier = Modifier.clickable { // clickable is not enabled
            // ...
        })
    }
}
```

I could roll my own (very simple) implementation using a `CompositionLocal`:

```kotlin
val LocalGesturesEnabled = compositionLocalOf { mutableStateOf(true) }

fun Modifier.myClickable(onClick: () -> Unit, enabled: Boolean = true) = composed {
    clickable(enabled = enabled && LocalGesturesEnabled.current.value, onClick)
}
```

But it won't work with third party composables or with more complex composables like `LazyList`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe the reason for the lack of such a system modifier is that you have to show the user that gestures are disabled by using different states for enabled/disabled controls, or by using a semi-transparent overlay view, etc.

But technically using [`pointerInput`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary?hl=hi#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInput(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) modifier you can get all touch events with [`awaitPointerEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/AwaitPointerEventScope#awaitPointerEvent(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerEventPass)).

With the `pass = PointerEventPass.Initial` parameter you will receive events before all child views, and then you can mark the event as handled with `consumeAllChanges`, so that children will no longer receive them.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.gesturesDisabled(disabled: Boolean = true) =
    if (disabled) {
        pointerInput(Unit) {
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                // we should wait for all new pointer events
                while (true) {
                    awaitPointerEvent(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
                        .changes
                        .forEach(PointerInputChange::consume)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        this
    }
```

If you wanna learn more about custom gesture processing, check out [this article](https://programs.wiki/wiki/using-jetpack-compose-to-complete-custom-gesture-processing.html)

Comment: if I set this modifier to the main BOX, i can't click on the any buttons

Comment: @saeednoshadi Yes, that what it does, it blocks any Composable touches in all children views.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have to return `this` instead of `Modifier` if not disabled to not lose all previously set modifier changes further up at the call site?

Comment: @ubuntudroid you're right, thanks for catching this

Comment: consumeAllChanges is deprecated

Comment: how to detect which gesture this pointerEvent is ?