# How can I make composables unclickable preferrably by its Modifier?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there a possibility to prohibit clickability? Not implementing the `onClick` interface might be one step. I also want to prevent the colored highlighting when tapping on it.

I've already tried `Modifier.clickable(enabled = false, onClick = {})`, but it still flashes when tapping on it.

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69146178/3585796). Note that it'll disable all the gestures, not only clicks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `indication` to null:

```kotlin
inline fun Modifier.disableClickAndRipple(): Modifier = composed {
    clickable(
        enabled = false,
        indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
        onClick = { },
    )
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I'm applying it to a `Chip` modifier and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: For Chip what worked for me was:
```Chip(interactionSource = remember { NoRippleInteractionSource() })```